# Controlling sliding divs with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Im making a page with a full screen div and overflow hidden. There are 3 divs off each of the left, bottom and right of the screen with corresponding buttons that make these divs slide onto the page (using margin settings to move them on and off).

I have this working with very simple code, but need more advanced code to remember what state the page is in, so the same button doesn't move the div again or so that each div is pushed back to its original position when another button is pressed.

My idea was that it could be something like

Set initial pagestate = 1

if pagestate = 1 (no buttons pressed, no divs shown)

button 1 onlcick animate div1 onto page, set pagestate = 2 
 button 2 onlcick animate div2 onto page, set pagestate = 3
 button 3 onlcick animate div3 onto page, set pagestate = 4

else if pagestate = 2 (button 1 pressed and div 1 showing)

button 1 onlcick do nothing 
 button 2 onlcick animate div2 onto page, animate div1 off page, set pagestate = 3
 button 3 onlcick animate div3 onto page, animate div1 off page, set pagestate = 4

etc.

I am using the code below and would appreciate it if anyone could help me get this working the way I envision

Working code:

```
    $('#button1').click(function() {
      $('#div1').animate({
      'marginLeft' : "+=100%"
       });
     });
```

How I imagine this might work:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var state = 1;


$('#button1').click(function() {


    if (state = 1) {    

    $('#div1').animate({
    'marginleft' : "+=100%" 
    });


    state = 2;

    }

    else if (state = 3) {

         $('#div1').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=100%" 
         }); 

           $('#div2').animate({
        'marginTop' : "-=100%" 
         });    

      state = 2;

      }

      else if (state = 4) {

         $('#div1').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=100%" 
         }); 

           $('#div4').animate({
        'marginRight' : "-=100%" 
         }); 

      state = 2;

       }

continued for each of the other 2 buttons.
```

This doesn't appear to work, and I am sure there is a much more elegant and efficient way to achieve this, so if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you just please clarify the concept? What happens with the buttons once a DIV comes into view? If I get it right (a draw picturing the idea would help...:| ), in the initial state you have `1 2 3` and below "2" you have `4`; `2` is the first one to appear, right?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Based on the code below, I've made a mockup here: http://jsfiddle.net/andyj/sprrxzgu/

Comment: Are you happy with it? (p.s, I'd suggest to put also a `home` or `back` something button at the top cause it's not logic at first that to return to the main screen you need to click i.e: `button2` (again)) think about UX while building UI.

Comment: Yes I am happy thanks, I will have a logo at the top of the page so I could use that as a home, also I need to deactivate the buttons after press so they don't hide the div they are showing.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CJ_/k4qyoufo/

This is one of several ways to go about it, hopefully will be useful (and is roughly what you're looking for!)

Start off by defining an array of 'states' - in this example I have explicitly used the values of the margins as the states, but could equally be set to 0s and 1s or something with the logic modified accordingly. These set the state for each div rather than 1 for each scenario (means in this case 3 different state values opposed to 8 if had one for each combination of visible divs!)

```
var states = [-100, 100, 100];
```

Then for each button, define a function that modifies the states array as required (set this div's value to toggle and the others to be off screen) and then call an update function:

```
$('#but1').click(function() {
    states[0]=(states[0]==0)?-100:0;
    states[1]=100;
    states[2]=100;
    update();
});

$('#but2').click(function() {
    states[0]=-100;
    states[1]=(states[1]==100)?0:100;
    states[2]=100;
    update();
});

$('#but3').click(function() {
    states[0]=-100;
    states[1]=100;
    states[2]=(states[2]==0)?100:0;
    update();
});
```

This function then sets the appropriate margins to the values you desire given the button press.

```
function update() {
    $('#div1').animate({
        'marginLeft' : states[0] + "%"
    });
    $('#div2').animate({
        'marginTop' : states[1] + "%"
    });
    $('#div3').animate({
        'marginLeft' : states[2] + "%"
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is a really nice solution! For the initial click, the div comes down from the top of the screen, then subsequently it works ok. Also when the div on the screen, the corresponding button is still active.


(Note: the margin technique is more tricky for the button 3, Im still trying to figure out how to position that so it works)



http://jsfiddle.net/andyj/sprrxzgu/

Comment: Whoops I missed your jsfiddle. Thanks I try and use that

Comment: @amj I repeat a quick drawing in paint or any other tool would help to understand better the initial state, the buttons states etc... cause exactly as CJ did it it's the exact way you explained it in your Q. and the way I would probably do it also.

Comment: I learn't from your jsfiddle and have it working now!! Thanks for the help

http://jsfiddle.net/andyj/sprrxzgu/2/

Comment: @amj glad you got it working :) sorry wasn't around to clarify - apologies I realise I misread your question and you didn't want a button to do anything once its corresponding div came on screen. To fix this (if you haven't already!) you just need to change the onclick functions to set the div on screen and remove the ternary if statement

Comment: i.e. for the first button click, change: states[0]=(states[0]==0)?-100:0; for states[0]=0;